# facing issue with add_legend() in seaborn matplotlib python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(Haberman_Dataset, hue='status', height=5)
g.map(plt.scatter,"status","nodes")
g.add_legend(title="Surv Status",label_order=['Lev 1', 'Lev -2'])
plt.show()
```

I am unable to modify legend name
[First Image this is default one-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puZcb.png)
Here instead of 1,2 i want to rename legend

[This is second image -- I added code  what i am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU3Tl.png)

Color is not reflecting as per legend

Comment: I am not able to duplicate an errors, you code is working as expected for me.  Seaborn version 0.9.0.

Comment: Do you really think with the lines of code you provided, people can reproduce this figure? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Think is that I am newcomer, and trying to solve a problem where I am stuck, actually - I am able to give label name but label wise colour is not reflecting... please try to understand, maybe my bad English you guys are not understanding.

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

```
Haberman_Dataset['Surv_status'] = Haberman_Dataset['Surv_status'].map({1:"Yes", 2:"No"})
g = sns.FacetGrid(Haberman_Dataset, hue="Surv_status",height=5)
g = g.map(plt.scatter,"Surv_status","axil_nodes_det").add_legend(title='Survival Status')
```

first line of code -- we can map with other legend name

++Solved